# How to converse encode CryptoJS.AES.encrypt NodeJS to PHP

Tags: php, public-key-encryption, cryptojs, password-encryption

I want to convert this encoding function to PHP

But I couldn't find the corresponding crypto.publicEncrypt and CryptoJS.AES.encrypt functions in PHP

Code NodeJS

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const Base64 = require('crypto-js/enc-base64');
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
function decodeData(data, privateKey) {
    let dataByte = Buffer.from(data.substring(0, 344), "base64")
    let origData = crypto.privateDecrypt({ key: privateKey, padding: 1 }, dataByte);
    let newKey = Base64.parse(origData.toString())

    let decodeData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data.substring(344), newKey, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    return decodeData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}

function encodeData(str, key) {
    let strRandom = (Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)).substring(0, 32)
    let strByte = Buffer.from(strRandom, "utf8")
    let strBase64 = Base64.parse(strRandom);
    let newEncode = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(str, strBase64, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    return crypto.publicEncrypt({ key: key, padding: 1 }, strByte).toString("base64") + "@@@@@@" + newEncode.toString();
}
```